# Change default of where Grafana sends alerts to to "external"

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm setting up a stack of Grafana, Prometheus and the Prometheus alert manager via docker, heavily relying on provisioning of all the configuration such as alert rules, dashboards and so on.

Because I will have to use the Prometheus alert manager, I want Grafana to be configured such, that it sends its alerts to the external alert manager.

Is there a possibility of setting this via any kind of configuration files instead of having to go on the Grafana Page and changing it manually in the Admin tab in Alerting?

I checked around a bit, but neither on the page about [Grafana Configuration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/) nor about [Alert Provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/) I could find anything that would sound fitting to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem and I though I'll share it with you in case somebody ever needs something like it.

It is possible to set the necessary config via Grafana's endpoint at `http://grafana/api/v1/ngalert/admin_config`, to which you have to post the value `'{"alertmanagersChoice":"external"}'`. (respectively `internal` for the internal alert manager or `all` for both.)

So basically I just define another container in the docker-compose.yml with the `curlimages/curl:latest` image, that sends exactly this message to my Grafana container, as soon as it's fully started:

```
services:
...
    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:latest-ubuntu
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f localhost/api/health"]
            interval: 10s
            retries: 10

...
    config_container:
        container_name: config_container
        depends_on:
            grafana:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: curlimages/curl:latest
        networks:
            - grafana
        command: >-
            -X POST --user admin:admin http://grafana/api/v1/ngalert/admin_config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"alertmanagersChoice":"external"}'
```

It might not be the perfect solution, as manual changes to the chosen alert manager done via the UI will be overwritten every time I start everything, but for my requirements that's good enough currently.